# Error while using nltk wordnet module

Tags: nltk

I want to use nltk wordnet module in my python code.I have allready installed nltk,but it is giving some error msg when I am writing ->

> > > from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn   (no error,it import successfully)
> > >       wn.synsets('idle') (It is giving error msg as -> object module has no attribute named 'synsets')

Comment: Could you please report this to NLTK bug tracker? https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues?sort=updated&state=open

Comment: Also, what NLTK version and Python version do you use?